# Socket connection between JavaScript client and Android server

Tags: javascript, android, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have an Android server socket and need connect a "web client" locally.

This is my Android server socket:

```
package com.artificioo.remotesetup;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.util.Log;

import com.artificioo.util.Utils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by artificioo on 11/05/16.
 */
public class RemoteSetupServer extends Thread {

    private final Context context;
    private ArrayList<ScanResult> scanResults = null;
    private ArrayList<RemoteSetupIndividualServer> individualServers;

    public RemoteSetupServer(Context context, ArrayList<ScanResult> scanResults) {
        this.context = context;
        this.scanResults = scanResults;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Utils.showToastInformationFastOnlyBeta(context, "run RemoteSetupServer");
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
            serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(CommunicationProtocol.SERVER_PORT));

            individualServers = new ArrayList<>();
            Utils.showToastInformationFastOnlyBeta(context, "Server online");
            boolean listening = true;
            while (listening) {
                try {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    clientSocket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
                    RemoteSetupIndividualServer individualServer =
                            new RemoteSetupIndividualServer(clientSocket, scanResults, this);
                    individualServer.start();
                    for (int i = 0; i < individualServers.size(); i++) {
                        RemoteSetupIndividualServer remoteControlIndividualServer =
                                individualServers.get(i);
                        if (clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress().equals(
                                remoteControlIndividualServer.getClientSocket().getInetAddress()
                                        .getHostAddress())) {
                            Utils.showToastInformationFastOnlyBeta(context, "Client removed");
                            individualServers.remove(i);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    individualServers.add(individualServer);
                } catch (IOException | VerifyError e) {
//                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Utils.showToastInformationFastOnlyBeta(context, "Server stop");
            Log.i(CommunicationProtocol.TAG, "Server stop");

            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Utils.showToastInformationFastOnlyBeta(context, "Server stop (exception)");
            Log.i(CommunicationProtocol.TAG, "Server stop (exception)");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public int getClientCount() {
        return individualServers.size();
    }

    void disconnectMe(RemoteSetupIndividualServer remoteControlIndividualServer) {
        individualServers.remove(remoteControlIndividualServer);
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

I'm trying use an JavaScript client in 2 different ways, but I'm having problems.

---

Way 1:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket;

        socket= new WebSocket('ws://192.168.43.1:44345');
        socket.onopen= function() {
            alert("is open");    
        };
        socket.onmessage= function(s) {
            //alert('got reply '+s);
        };  

        socket.onerror = function(evt) { console.log(evt); };
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Response 1:

> testSocket.html:8 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.43.1:44345/'
>   failed: Error during WebSocket handshake:
>   net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

---

Way 2:

```
<html>

    <head>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.43.1:44345');
        socket.on('connect', function(){
            alert("is open");
        });
        socket.on('event', function(data){});
        socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
        </script> 

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>

</html>
```

Response 2:

> polling-xhr.js:261 GET
>   http://192.168.43.1:44345/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LjTe5ai
>   net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

---

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: When I made a game server back in the day(in java, but the classes are still present) you would be able to connect to an android device using Sockets and ServerSocket. If you need JS for some reason, then ignore this comment

Comment: What does the server code look like? It is a websocket server?

Comment: I just added the Android server socket code @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: May be the error is on your socket server, are you using node js for your socket server?

Comment: It looks like a normal socket, web sockets require a web socket server.

Comment: Mmm ok. There is no way to connect a web socket with a normal server socket @SamiKuhmonen?

Comment: No, the server has to speak the correct protocoo

Comment: Okey. Maybe I can use a node.js server socket in my Android. I'll try. Thanks for you response @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: Do you understand that a `WebSocket` is not a normal TCP socket.  It has an HTTP connection initiation which is then "upgraded" to the webSocket protocol and then uses a specific webSocket security and data frame format.  To handle incoming webSocket connections from a browser, you MUST have a server that speaks the webSocket protocol.  You can see more about how it all works here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers.